# What is the difference between Linear Interpolation factor and Sampling rate conversion factor?

Tags: interpolation, resampling

I have come across sampling rate conversion factor, which is given by:

```
                             S_factor = F_new/F_old
```

If F_new > F_old, then s_factor > 1

and

If F_new < F_old, then s_factor < 1

But, what is this "linear interpolation factor"?. Is it the same as sampling rate conversion factor?

Does the linear interpolation factors value should be in the range 0 to 1?, If so, why is that?

Comment: Can you provide a reference or definition of "linear interpolation factor" Where did come across this?

Comment: Source/Reference - Julius O.Smith* & Phil Gosett** "A Flexible Sampling Rate Conversion Method" IEEE, 1984.

Comment: Even this paper uses almost the same implementation - https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/resample.pdf

Comment: Julius - Page No : 19.4.2 & ccrma - Page No : 11

Comment: In the explanation they have mentioned "Consider a sampling rate conversion by a factor S_factor" and have also mention interpolation factor as "n", whose value should be between 0 to 1. So, confused as to what they are referring the interpolation factor to.

Comment: Look at Fig. 7 on page 11 where you will see the linear interpolation factor, n. It is used to determine an intermediate value between two samples. When you want to determine a sample value between two existing samples, one way is linear interpolation. Say you want to increase the rate by 10/9, i.e. the time resolution of the new samples are 0.9 of the old ones. First, start with sample 0, then, compute the linear interpolation between sample 0 and 1 with n = 0.9. Next sample should be at time 1.8, so n = 0.8 for samples 1 and 2. Time 2.7 gives n = 0.2 and so on. So, no, they are not the same.

Comment: Also, note that the linear interpolation factor is eta, $\eta$, not n (but due to character limits I had to use n in my comment). Fig. 7 can be a bit confusing otherwise...

Comment: @Oscar, I got the point of estimating intermediate samples between l and i+1 samples. But what is that "time resolution"?. Can you please elaborate on that as to how is it used for calculation of interpolation factor?.

Comment: OK. With sample rate conversion factor $S$, you want to compute samples at time $\frac{i}{S}$ for $i=0, 1, 2, \dots$. What I called time resolution is simply $1/S$, the time between the "new" samples, based on the time between the old samples, $1$. The linear interpolation factor is simply then the fractional part of $\frac{i}{S}$ for each $i$ with the integer part telling which sample index to use (together the next) for the linear interpolation. Can be written in a more formal way though, but not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll move my comments to an answer:

With sample rate conversion factor $S$, you want to compute samples at "time" $\frac{i}{S}$ for $i=0,1,2,\dots$. "Time" relating to the index of the previous series. The linear interpolation factor is simply then the fractional part of $\frac{i}{S}$ for each $i$ with the integer part telling which sample index to use (together the next) for the linear interpolation.

Simple example to clarify: upsample a sequence a factor $\frac{10}{9}$. You would like to determine the samples at "time" $0, 0.9, 1.8, 2.7, 3.6, \dots$.  First, start with sample $0$, then, compute the linear interpolation between sample $0$ and $1$ with $\eta = 0.9$. Next sample should be at "time" $1.8$, so $\eta = 0.8$ for samples $1$ and $2$. "Time" $2.7$ gives $\eta = 0.7$ for samples $2$ and $3$ and so on.

Note that you conceptually can compute the "time" $1.8$ sample from sample $0$ and $1$ with $\eta = 1.8$, but using sample $1$ and $2$ with $\eta = 0.8$ is better. So while $\eta$ does not *really* have to be $0$ and $1$ the results will be better and there is no advantage to not have it in that range.